# More efficient ways to find the number of matching values shared by two iterables?

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting, matching

**EDIT: Looking for the number of matches not the matches themselves. Cannot solve with sets or `[x for x in list1 if x in list2]` type manner. `list1.count(x) if x in list2` works though.**

Let's say you have two lists, list1 and list2, and want to find the number of times a value from list1 matches a value from list2.

I used the following code to perform this task successfully -

```
sum([x==y for x in list1 for y in list2])
```

The problem is this code cannot handle larger lists efficiently. Is there a faster, more efficient, dare I say more pythonic way to solve this problem than the "double for" loop?

Comment: Look into _set intersection_

Comment: `len(set(list1) & set(list2))` will work so long as neither `list1` nor `list2` has duplicate elements

Comment: Or, use part of that approach if you don't want both converting to sets (which will remove duplicates). `set2 = set(list2); sum([item in set2 for item in list1])`

Comment: ``list`` has a ``count`` method which is more efficient than your 0/1 loop, but your query still is O(n^2). So ``sum(list1.count(x) for x in list2)`` will be faster, but still scale badly.

Comment: Yeah has to handle duplicates. Thanks @roganjosh

Comment: @MisterMiyagi `count` worked better, thanks

Comment: @slurrr Is your intended result for num_dups([1,1], [1, 1]) 2 or 4?

Comment: @AdamVanProoyen 4

Comment: @slurrr: since you need to handle duplicates then please post an MRE example of list1, list2 with duplicates. Are the elements ints, floats, strings, arbitrary objects?

Comment: Since your lists are unordered and can have duplicates, you could use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). If your answer should factor in multiplicity, then e.g.: `c1 & c2` gives `Counter({'b': 2, 'd': 1, 'h': 1, 'e': 1})`, and `(c1 & c2).total()` gives simply 5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Counters support multiset intersections with the `&` operator:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> list1 = list("abba")   
>>> list2 = list("bbanana") 
>>> c1 = Counter(list1)
>>> c2 = Counter(list2)
>>> sum(c1[k]*c2[k] for k in c1 & c2)  # O(n)
10
>>> sum([x==y for x in list1 for y in list2])  # O(n**2)
10
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `Counter` found in the Python standard library.

Counter counts the number of times an item is found in an iterable. Constructing it from a list essentially yields a map from each item in the list to the number of occurrences.

Performing set intersection on two Counter's will give us the counts for items found in both lists. However, instead of finding the number of duplicates, we are looking for the number of times an element matches another element. This means we need to use multiplication instead of min for set intersection.

```py
from collections import Counter

def merge(d1, d2):
  return {k: (d1[k], d2[k]) for k in d1 if k in d2}

def num_dups(l1, l2):
  c1, c2 = Counter(l1), Counter(l2)
  dups = merge(c1, c2)
  return sum(x * y for x, y in dups.values())
```

Comment: @wim yeah you're right. I'll try to confirm with slurrr what the intended behavior is.  The idea for this method should be about the same (set intersection with multiplication instead of taking the min as the join operator)

Comment: Yeah that is a great function but does not count the dups multiple times to give you the total number

Comment: @AdamVanProoyen see wim's answer

Answer (score 0):

This approach is radically different from the others, and possibly too simplistic for your requirements - but thought I'd throw it in the mix.

It addresses this request:

- Let's say you have two lists, list1 and list2, **and want to find the number of times a value from list1 matches a value from list2.**

How about:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
b = ['a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'c']

[b.count(i) for i in a]
```

#### Output:

```
[2, 0, 3, 0, 0]
```

Comment: This actually works and was the first way I got my code working on larger lists. Not sure why the down votes I wish someone would explain what is so bad about this code other than it is not the most efficient.

Comment: @slurrr - Thank you.  I like it because it's simple and works.  I'd like an explanation on the downvotes as well.  Thanks though.

Comment: This is still O(n**2)-ish - `b.count(i)` iterates `b` entirely for every element in `a`.  I am not your downvoter.

Comment: You may want to benchmark this -- its scalability is worse than the Counter solutions, but it is probably much faster for small lists. It would be useful to know where the break-even point is.