# Find the size of intersection between two lists

Tags: python, list, recursion, set-intersection

I'm trying to write a function that returns the number of common elements between two lists. If the element occurs `j` times in `L1` and `k` times in `L2`, the minimum of `j` and `k` elements are shared.

Examples:

```
L1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
L2 = [4, 2]
L3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]
intersection_size ( L1 , L2 ) => 2
intersection_size ( L1 , L3 ) => 5
```

My thought was to sort `L1` and `L2` in ascending order and then compare each element:

```
def intersection(L1, L2):
    dL1 = L1[:]
    dL2 = L2[:]
    dL1.sort()
    dL2.sort()
    if dL1[1:] == [] or dL2[1:] == []:
        return 0
    if dL1[0] == dL2[0]:
        return 1 + intersection(dL1[1:], dL2[1:])
    elif dL1[0] > dL2[0]:
        return 0 + intersection(dL1, dL2[1:])
    elif dL1[0] < dL2[0]:
        return 0 + intersection(dL1[1:], dL2)
```

However when I test `intersection([1, 6, 1, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4])`, the function gives me 1 instead of 2. Can someone please tell me which part is wrong?

I created `dL1` and `dL2` since I want `L1` and `L2` to stay the same for other purpose, and since I'm a beginner, I'm only allowed to use basic recursion and abstract list functions to do this.

Comment: Dupe:  [More efficient ways to find the number of matching values shared by two iterables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58597916/674039)

Comment: Why does being a beginner mean that you aren't allowed to use the Python standard library? That's a non-sequitur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part is logically incorrect:

```py
    if dL1[1:] == [] or dL2[1:] == []:
        return 0
```

The base case should be when one or both lists are empty. But you are returning 0 when one or both lists have a single element. That's incorrect because that element could still be a match, so the size of the intersection would not be 0. If you change this condition to `dL1 == [] or dL2 == []` then it works:

```py
>>> intersection(L1, L2)
2
>>> intersection(L1, L3)
5
>>> intersection([1, 6, 1, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4])
2
>>> intersection([1, 1, 1, 2, 2], [1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
4
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will work

```
len(set(L1) & set(L3))
```

If you dont want to use `sets`, you can do the following:

```
def intersection(L1, L2):
    return len([x for x in L1 if x in L2])
```

Comment: No need to convert to a list; `len` works fine on a set.

Comment: It does not work well, per OP's spec, the expected result for `[1, 1, 2]` and `[1, 1, 3]` is `2`, while your method gives `1`.

Comment: the user has given the requirement as `intersection_size ( L1 , L3 ) => 5`

Comment: Also, the requirement is *"I'm only allowed to use basic recursion and abstract list functions to do this"*. But this answer (if edited to note the differences) could be useful because other people will not necessarily have the exact same requirements.

Comment: When there are repeated values, `len([x for x in L1 if x in L2)` will use the count from L1, rather than the min count for both lists.

Comment: sorry i didnt get you